# How to back to ajax request if exit webpage

Tags: php, ajax

How i can back to ajax request? for examplek I enter the webpage, start ajax request and progress bar is moving forwarde and for example I exit this page and back there, how to return to active/started ajax request ? how to not start this function again but if is running just back to this request.

that`s my ajax code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


                setTimeout(getProgress,100);
              $('.stan').text('Pobieram analizę...');
              $.urlParam = function(name){
             var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
                            if (results==null){
                               return null;
                            }
                            else{
                               return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
                            }
                                    }
        var id = $.urlParam('id');
        var idt = $.urlParam('idt');

                  $.ajax({
                                 url: "views/getresults.php?id="+id+"&idt="+idt,

                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#loadresults").append(data);
                    }
                });
                setTimeout(getProgress,100);

            return false;


            function getProgress(){

                $.ajax({

                    url: 'views/listen.php',
                    cache: false,
                   success: function(data) {
                        if(data<= 95 && data >= 0){
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#loadresults').html(data);
                            $('#progress').attr('aria-valuenow', data);
                            $('#progress').css('width', data + "%");  
                            $('#progress').text(data + "%");    

                            setTimeout(getProgress,1000);
                            console.log('Repeat');

                        }
                         else {
                            $('#progress').attr('aria-valuenow', 100);
                            $('#progress').css('width', 100 + "%");  

                            $('#progress').text(100 + "%");    

                            $('.stan').text('Dane zostały pobrane');
                                                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        document.getElementById('progress').style.visibility = "hidden";
                                        },1000);
                         setTimeout(function(){
                                        document.getElementById('stan').style.visibility = "hidden";
                                        },1200);


                            console.log('End');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question by improving the English.

Comment: Not 100% I understand, but by the sounds of it, might be worth looking into `$_SESSIONS`?

Comment: Example: Enter website, click start in ajax, exit webpage. Then again enter webpage, check if ajax request is in pending if is back to status of actually % of proggress bar or just back to actual position of ajax request, not starting this ajax again like is now. If request exsist back to him and retrive results...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is technically impossible.

If you exit a web page (by navigating away from it, or closing the browser), everything on the page is destroyed. Next time you go there, your browser reloads the page again from the server (or possibly, from a cache) and starts again. That's because navigating to a URL in the browser makes a brand new HTTP request to the server. There is no such thing as the "previous" ajax request. Once you navigate away from the page the first time, it's like it never existed. None of the code or content on that previous copy of the page exists any more.

The web is *stateless*.  This is a key concept you should be aware of. It means that nothing is preserved from one request to the next. The way applications preserve state is by taking active measures to use things like cookies, server-side sessions, databases etc to provide persistent storage. But you cannot do anything equivalent to resurrect an in-progress ajax request which was orphaned by closing its host page.

Your only workaround is to keep the page open. If the user wants to navigate to another page, by using a link or button on that page, you should ensure that it opens the link in another tab/window. Of course if the user takes independent action (e.g typing a new address in the browser, using back/forward buttons) there is nothing you can do to stop them.